# Magento 2.2.5 customer login not working

Tags: login, customer-account, magento-2.2.5

Working on a new Magento2.2.5 install and when I test logging into the site as a customer the magento signin page just reloads with no error message shown. However in the admin panel I see my test customer listed. I don't see anything in the system.log file so I am not sure where to begin with troubleshooting? Suggestions?

Comment: What your your main host name ?

Comment: Please check browser console errors, error logs on the server, etc.
This flow is covered with different kind of automated tests and unlikely to be broken out of the box.

Comment: And for a once check different browser, just to be a sure

Comment: Try login with firefox mozilla browser and check.